# python 3 import not working

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am new to Python 3 and am rewriting a Python 2 program. I have the following file system:

```
|-00_programs / test.py
|-01_classes / class_scrapper.py
```

I want to import the class `scrapper` from the file `class_scrapper`:

Here is `class_scrapper.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from    urllib.request     import urlopen
from    bs4                import BeautifulSoup
class scrapper: 
    def get_html(self, url):
        html    = False
        headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)' }
        try:
            html      = urlopen(url, '', headers).read()
        except Exception as e:
            print ("Error getting html :" + str(e))
        return html
```

Here is `test.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import  sys
sys.path.insert(0, "./../01_classes/class_scrapper.py")
from  class_scrapper import scrapper
o_scrapper = scrapper()
```

While executing I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/00_programs/tets.py", line 6, in     <module>
    from  class_scrapper import scrapper
ImportError: No module named 'class_scrapper'
```

What should be changed on the `import` command to make that work?

Thanks,

Romain.

Comment: I suggest you read up on [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). Also, it's "scraper", and please read [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the interpreter is saying module doesn't exist, it means you must have spelt it wrong when importing, or the module is either not in your program's directory or the python directory which has all of the other main modules.